# Do I need to change my tyres for a week of riding around Loch Lomond

Tags: tire

I have a comfortable Viking bike with its original tyres. I off for a week around Loch Lomond and plan to cycle on the various tracks around the area... http://www.lochlomond-trossachs.org/things-to-do/cycling/cycling-routes/

[image: This is the type of tyre I have]

Would these 700 x 38c tyres be suitable for the terrain in this area or should I get better tyres. If so which tyres would be best.

Comment: As your link includes both "hard" mountain bike trails and road routes it's going to be very hard for us to say, especially with just a brand of bike. A mountain bike that can handle the trails will be slow on road but you'll survive. A road bike that will be quick on the roads would struggle on the trails though an expert could probably get through most of it. As those are the stock tyres you've probably got a hybrid. So the road would be fine, but the mountain bike trails probably not - but for the bike as much as the tyres. Forest roads would be ok too. More details on the bike please.

Comment: Please include which types of tracks you want to ride and more details about the bicycle (including the name of the tires).

Comment: A pair of cyclocross tyres might be the solution. The regulation width is 32mm but you can get wider ones (35-38mm)

Comment: @Carel: It really depends on the type of track. If the current tires work okay-ish with lower pressure they should be fine on gravel and easy mountainbike trails as long as there is no mud or grass. Good cyclocrosstires (Schwalbe Racing Ralph, Michelin Mud etc.) would certainly improve things but might be overkill, especially if the rest of the bicycle is totally unsuitable for the terrain.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned... I will only be doing light rides... the bike is just a Viking Westminster. The ones I'm looking at are mostly cycle routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Light rides on cycle routes?  I think you're OK....just bring a spare tube and repair tools!

Comment: I tend to pack a spare tube and another per 100 km of ride, so a 200 km ride would be 3 tubes.  The only time I ran out was in a 2km to work, where I missed the sharp thing and punctured the single spare immediately, then had to walk.